# How to fill different colours in multiple polygons Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I try to built maps with multiple polygons but I had problem when I combined the colours.

I made 5 polygons and I filled 5 colours, but the result's only show 2 colours.

Example code :

```
var map;
var infoWindow;
var bermudaTriangle = new Array();


// Angular controllers etc


function initialize() {

  // map options
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.176037, 106.827142), 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  };


  // initialize 
  //var bermudaTriangle;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


  // define map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // ************** POLYGON 1 **************************************************

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.

    var coorArray = [[[........]]];

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray[0].length; i++) { 
      element1 = coorArray[0][i][1];
      element2 = coorArray[0][i][0];
      triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }


  // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[0] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#GG5555',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF8533',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });


  // ************** POLYGON 2 **************************************************

  window.alert("size before: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  var coorArray2 = [[[..........]]];

  addNewPoly(coorArray2);

  window.alert("size after: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  for(var i=0,l=bermudaTriangle.length;i<l;i++) {
    bermudaTriangle[i].setMap(map);

    // map.fitBounds(bounds);


  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle[i], 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  }

function addNewPoly(coorArray2) {

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    window.alert("inside addNewPoly")

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray2[0].length; i++) { 
    element1 = coorArray2[0][i][1];
    element2 = coorArray2[0][i][0];
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[bermudaTriangle.length] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#GG5555',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF4D4D',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
}

   // ************** POLYGON 3**************************************************

  window.alert("size before: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  var coorArray3 = [[[................]]];

  addNewPoly(coorArray3);

  window.alert("size after: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  for(var i=0,l=bermudaTriangle.length;i<l;i++) {
    bermudaTriangle[i].setMap(map)

    // map.fitBounds(bounds);


  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle[i], 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  }

function addNewPoly(coorArray3) {

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    window.alert("inside addNewPoly")

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray3[0].length; i++) { 
    element1 = coorArray3[0][i][1];
    element2 = coorArray3[0][i][0];
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[bermudaTriangle.length] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#GG5555',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FFFF4D',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  }


  // ************** POLYGON 4 **************************************************

  window.alert("size before: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  var coorArray4 = [[[......................]]];

  addNewPoly(coorArray4);

  window.alert("size after: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  for(var i=0,l=bermudaTriangle.length;i<l;i++) {
    bermudaTriangle[i].setMap(map);

    // map.fitBounds(bounds);


  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle[i], 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  }

function addNewPoly(coorArray4) {

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    window.alert("inside addNewPoly")

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray4[0].length; i++) { 
    element1 = coorArray4[0][i][1];
    element2 = coorArray4[0][i][0];
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[bermudaTriangle.length] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#GG5555',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#A375FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  }

  // ************** POLYGON 5**************************************************

  window.alert("size before: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  var coorArray5= [[[.................]]];

  addNewPoly(coorArray5);

  window.alert("size after: " + bermudaTriangle.length)

  for(var i=0,l=bermudaTriangle.length;i<l;i++) {
    bermudaTriangle[i].setMap(map);

    // map.fitBounds(bounds);


  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle[i], 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  }

function addNewPoly(coorArray5) {

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    window.alert("inside addNewPoly")

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray5[0].length; i++) { 
    element1 = coorArray5[0][i][1];
    element2 = coorArray5[0][i][0];
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[bermudaTriangle.length] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#GG5555',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#4DFF4D',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  return bermudaTriangle;  

  }
```

Comment: You may want to shorten the code to only the relevant parts. This is REALLY kind of long.

Comment: And the parts you have removed (the polygon coordinates) are required to reproduce the problem.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: **https://tripulous.me/trip-detail-4-1.html** it's your mean ???

Comment: @PaulWilliams yaa i know that.. sorry i just studied about that and not try to use database yet

Comment: @geocodezip because the coordinates is too long but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @HoangHieu sorry i couldn't open your link because there's risk when entering your website

Comment: Don't wory, My page doesn't get anything from you :), my https error because mysetting in VPS ERROR :) **process unsafe**

Comment: @HoangHieu yaa can you tell me the other link for example ? i rebuild my code

Comment: waiting, I capturing my web page.

Comment: Here, https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/ps9v, If this is sample, waiting me minute I will tell you how I can do this :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If your actual coordinates are too long, provide a simple example (some triangles would work), and test your code to verify it exhibits the issue with the simplified polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple functions with the same name (`addNewPoly`). The particular browser will choose one.

Also `#GG5555` is not a valid color.

One possible solution, create one function, pass the desired colors in as additional arguments.

```
function addNewPoly(coorArray, strokeColor, fillColor) {

    var triangleCoords = new Array();
    var element1;
    var element2;

    window.alert("inside addNewPoly")

    for (i = 0; i < coorArray[0].length; i++) { 
    element1 = coorArray[0][i][1];
    element2 = coorArray[0][i][0];
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(element1, element2));
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle[bermudaTriangle.length] = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: strokeColor,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: fillColor,
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  return bermudaTriangle;  

  }
```

Or you could create a different function for each coordinate array (`addNewPoly5()`).

Comment: let me try different funtion in this code... strokeColor and fillColor still use hex color right ?